# How does change detection on control work when form is patched?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-changedetection

I was wondering what happens with the following:

I have a formGroup with these controls:

```
{
  forename: new FormControl()
  surname: new FormControl()
}
```

now I track changes of the control 'surname' like this (just an example):

```
this.formGroup.get('surname').valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
   if(this.formGroup.get('forename') == 'Max'){
      this.formGroup.get('forename').disable();
   }
})
```

and at the end I am patching my form like this:

`this.formGroup.patchForm({surname: 'Muster', forename: 'Max'});`

Would the control 'forename' be disabled? Because I am not sure if it would trigger the change of the control 'surname' before it could set the value of the control 'forename'. Therefore 'forename' probably does not have the 'correct' value yet.

I am trying to understand better, when exactle valueChanges events are triggered, since I sometimes have the problem, that values are not set, though they should be.

I was also wondering if it is possible to wait until every control is patched and then emit the changes.

Comment: try `valueChanges` on whole form object. that will trigger if any value on the form is changed and then you can use `filter` operator to filter the type. something like `this.form.valueChanges.filter(x => x).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Not sure how I would do that for a bigger form. I can do `this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(changes =>....)` which would give me an object of all the changes, but then I would have to compare that to an existing object to determine, what actually changed? 

I have probably more than 20 controls so that doesn't seem a good solution. Not sure how I should "filter" it, since there is not something like a filter-Function.

Comment: If I change the order of props in update object to: `{ forname: 'Max', surname: 'Muster' }` then everything seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reason:**

`valueChanges` for `surname` would trigger as soon as the `patchValue()` updates the first property, therefore you'd get `null` as value for `forename` and the condition `this.formGroup.get('forename') == 'Max'` would be `false`.

**Solution 1:**

You can `subscribe()` to `valueChanges` of the whole `formGroup` instead of single control and then check for the condition required. Like this:

```
this.formGroup
      .valueChanges // subscribe to all changes
      .pipe(
        filter(form => form.forename === 'Max') // check if 'forname' is 'Max'
      ).subscribe(
        forename => this.formGroup.get('forename').disable() // disable control
      );
```

**Solution 2:**

You can get the desired behavior with your code by just changing the order of props in object to update. Like this:

```
this.formGroup.patchForm({ forename: 'Max', surname: 'Muster' });
```

**[Working Demo with Solution 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hgttxq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation! I actually considered to go with Solution 2, but I don't want to run into errors just because properties in an object do not have a specific order.. Solution 1 is also very interesting!

Lastly I decided to basically put another valueChanges-Subscription on the forename (I will answer my own question to demonstrate). Which is maybe not the cleanest, but for my project it was not an option to rebuild all the valueChanges events to match something similar like the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
this.formGroup.get('surname').valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
   this.handleForenameControl();
})

this.formGroup.get('forename').valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
   this.handleForenameControl();
})

private handleForenameControl():void{
  if(this.formGroup.get('forename') == 'Max'){
      this.formGroup.get('forename').disable();
   }
}
```

I know this is not the cleanest and I was considering not to put another valueChanges-Subscription, but yeah.

I mean the above was just an example and no code that I was actually using in a project, so the example might be bad. Maybe this still helps someone.

Comment: isn't this same as solution 1 of answer? I mean, subscribing to change of all values of form or subscribing to change of all values individually? at least in this case, where the controls are only 2. and yes, its not the cleanest way but if it works for you and not part of actual project then I guess its good to go :)

Comment: lastly, if you could explain about why won't you go with solution 1 then may be I could be able to update it as required.